# How do I get my app to update my library consistently?

Tags: angular, angular-library

So I've written a library with a component like this in it in Angular 14:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'site-container[headerDataStorage]',
  templateUrl: 'site-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./site-container.component.scss'],
  ...
})
export class SiteContainerComponent {
  ...
}
```

I have now updated to angular 16, in which the class names of `.mat-card` have changed to `.mat-mdc-card`, so I've changed my scss from:

```
.site-container {
  ...
  
  > .mat-card {
    ...
  }
}
```

to:

```
.site-container {
  ...

  > .mat-mdc-card {
    ...
  }
}
```

However, in the browser I cannot see any changes. I see the style for `.mat-site-container` but not the ones of `.mat-mdc-card`. Looking at the `<style>`-tag inserted by angular, I can see there's still the old css, namely: `.site-container > .mat-card ...`. But when I search for it in the corresponding node_modules folder via Visual Studio Code I can see the `site-container.mjs` contains the new style tags `.site-container > .mat-mdc-card`.
I assumed this was a cache issue at first but when I loaded the site on Firefox (for the first time, mind you), it had the same issue, old css in the `<style>`-tag.

Then, I commented the whole line `styleUrls: ['./site-container.component.scss'],` out to see if this was an issue with the library in general or just the scss. I reinstalled the library, no changes. Then, instead of just installing my library, I first uninstalled it, then installed it again, only to receive an error of an incorrect dependency between the angular/common@16.0.2 from my app and the angular/common@16.0.2 from the peerDependencies in my library. So I removed the peerDependency, installed again, worked - the browser had actually updated the commented out line and did not insert the css at all. It also updated the library in the node_modules of my app and now missed all the css as intended. So I commented the line back in, uninstalled, reinstalled, nothing. I looked in the `.mjs` in my node_modules, still contained the commented out line for the styleUrls. I added the peerDependency again, this time there was no dependency conflict (???), uninstall, reinstall ... still nothing. I can't get my css back in.

Why the hell does my angular library code not get updated every time? I never had any issues with this in angular 14. How do I get it to update *every time* I reinstall my library? I want to see every damn change I make. How is this so difficult and not the damn default behaviour?